# Cant't cancel an order via Amazon selling api

Tags: php, amazon-selling-partner-api

I want to cancel an order via Amazon Selling Partner API. I am using the
pkg jlevers/selling-partner-api : 3.1

this is my code

```
    //Api configuration
    $config = $this->config(); 
    $feedType = FeedType::POST_PRODUCT_IMAGE_DATA;
    $feedsApi = new FeedsV20210630Api($config);
    
    // Create Feed Docment
    $createFeedDocSpec = new Feeds\CreateFeedDocumentSpecification(['content_type' => $feedType['contentType']]);
    $feedDocumentInfo = $feedsApi->createFeedDocument($createFeedDocSpec);
    $feedDocumentId = $feedDocumentInfo->getFeedDocumentId();
    

    // Upload Document - xml 
    $feedContents = <<<EOD
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
        <Header>
                <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
                <MerchantIdentifier>A2CGYLKCS16T7R</MerchantIdentifier>
        </Header>
        <MessageType>OrderAcknowledgement</MessageType> 
        <Message>
                <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                <OrderAcknowledgement>
                    <AmazonOrderID>304-6263183-0171522</AmazonOrderID>
                    <StatusCode>Failure</StatusCode>
                    <Item>
                                    <AmazonOrderItemCode>B08PXLDKPX</AmazonOrderItemCode>
                                    <CancelReason>BuyerCanceled</CancelReason>
                    </Item>
                </OrderAcknowledgement>
        </Message> 
    </AmazonEnvelope>
    EOD;
    $docToUpload = new SellingPartnerApi\Document($feedDocumentInfo, $feedType);
    $docToUpload->upload($feedContents);
    

    // create Feed
    $body = new Feeds\CreateFeedSpecification([
        'feed_type' => $feedType["name"],
        "marketplace_ids" => ["A1VC38T7YXB528"],
        "input_feed_document_id" => $feedDocumentId,
    ]);
    

    $result = $feedsApi->createFeed($body);
    dd($result);
```

When I execute my code in my Laravel application it works and I receive a feed Id back.
After a couple of minutes, I checked with getFeed Function the process status and it was done.

But if I look in my Seller Central my order isn't canceled and appears as non shipped. Why it doesn't change